# linker error while using Parse framework and Facebook sdk framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

I moved a source code from another MAC machine to mine Mac, Previously the code was fine, when I stared building an error occurred `Parse.h` not found , after searching on google, I figured out that error after clearing that error Now, I am facing this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKSettings", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I AM NOT USING PODS in code.

Help me ! 
Thanks

Comment: Remove the Facebook framework from your parse framework bundle.

Comment: I need Facebook framework in project

Comment: I removed and re-added FacebookSDK framework still can't help myself. :(

Comment: you have to remove it from Parse bundle that ships with it.

Comment: sorry about that , but how do I remove that ?

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?